# Are 2008 100USD paper notes too old to be exchanged in the UK?

Tags: usa, uk, money, exchange

I have five 100 US$ notes, 2008 series. Can I change them to UK currency in the UK?

They are in perfect condition.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think you won't be able to change them?

Comment: There is a general opinion (and backed in real-life experience) that exchange booths outside the US will not accept older notes (because of fraud/counterfeit notes risk). The OP's question is in my opinion, how old can they be to be safely/easily exchanged.

Comment: @drat money exchanges in some countries require USD currency notes to be "not older than 20XX". Such exchanges either refuse to exchange the notes or give you a really bad exchange rate e.g. GCC countries.

Comment: @Newton do you have example of such countries ? Your statement seems to contradict Moo's answer.

Comment: Moo is talking about the UK only. I was clarifying to @drat that in some countries you cannot exchange older notes. For example in Oman you cannot exchange USD older than 2003.

Comment: 2009 is currently the most recent year for our $100 bills (the old currency fraud, is usually pre 1980s)

Comment: There is no 2008 series USD$100 note, so you are either mistaken about what they are or they are fake.  Do they say "Series 2008" on them?  Or something else?

Comment: @WELZ According to http://www.uspapermoney.info/general/chron_s.html series 2013 notes exist for the $100, and there will probably soon also be series 2017 notes (but as yet only $1 notes have been printed from that series)

Comment: They wouldn't take some ~5USD, ~1995 notes in a hotel at Rio de Janeiro last year, stating I should take them to the US for exchange for newer ones.

Comment: @EdmundDantes, "not older than" usually refers to when certain anti-counterfeiting measures were introduced, rather than simple age of the bills.

Comment: Why does the oldness of a bill matter for fraud? Oh, I see, the comment right above by Mark answers my question.

Answer (score 40):

Yes you can.

Unlike other countries, including the UK, US banknotes are never "withdrawn" and remain legal currency across the world however old they are (but you wouldn't want to spend the older ones as they are worth more than their face value as collectors items).

In the UK you can exchange them at most high street banks (NatWest, HSBC, Lloyds etc), any Post Office with a Foreign Currency desk, many travel agents (Thomas Cook etc), Marks and Spencer stores and high street bureau de change (currency exchange).

You may be charged an exchange fee, and you should shop around for the best rates.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71208/discussion-on-answer-by-moo-are-2008-100usd-paper-notes-too-old-to-be-exchanged).

Comment: Fwiw, all UK notes also remain legal currency, going back to 1694. They can simply be exchanged for notes in circulation at the Bank of England in Threadneedle Street during normal working hours, or by post.

Comment: @user6697063 The Bank of England will exchange them for current notes (presuming, of course, that they can verify their authenticity), but this should carefully not to be confused with the concept of "legal tender".  High street banks, shops, or any other persons are not required to accept historical or withdrawn notes as payment.  Most surviving historical notes, however, would likely command much higher prices as rare antiques and, so, a degree of suspicion as regards their authenticity would be expected should you simply decide to exchange them for current banknotes.

Comment: @J...dont confuse the concept of "legal tender" and "legal currency", they are two different things. A note can be one and not the other. :)

Comment: @Moo Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: You're right I shouldn't have called it "legal currency". But the rest of my comment as to what you can actually do (rather than which words to use) I still believe to be true, after rechecking.

Comment: @user6697063 I don't think there's anything wrong with calling it "legal currency" - I don't think it's a proper term or anything, but the idea being that the BoE will still honour the notes is correct.  Just wanted to make clear that the BoE honouring them doesn't mean that anyone else needs to.

Comment: @MatthewBarclay and my answer is about the ability to exchange currency in a foreign country - the legal tender part is about confirming that older US banknotes are still valid for exchange, as withdrawn foreign currency is almost universally rejected by currency exchanges because of the status.  Did you read my complete answer or just skimmed it?

Answer (score 7):

I've just been refused exchange of the new $100 bills at Tui, Post office and other places.

The staff uses following arguments:

- The amount is too big.
- It's the most forged note in the world.

Comment: What is Tui? A place?

Comment: Tui is one of the biggest travel agent chains in the UK.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted.  Do people think it is dishonest?  If not, it seems to be a valuable account of someone's actual experience having difficulty changing US $100 notes for reasons other than the age of the note or its design.  I've upvoted it.

Comment: Since US dollars are the most forged currency in the world, and $100 notes are too big to resell, it seems the employees are not ignorant at all. Insulting them gets you downvotes.

Comment: @phoog Well, neither an up- nor a downvote vote from me, it might be because the tone is a little abrasive (starting off with "Nonsense," and references to "ignorant staff"), and the assumption that people will know what "Tui Post" means.

Comment: @MikeHarris perhaps then it should be attributed to lack of punctuation.  There's no "Tui Post." It should say "...at TUI, Post office, and others."

Comment: @JorenVandamme regarding your proposed edit, please see my previous comment.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, since any exchange can refuse to exchange a note they are not familiar with (especially outside the US).  Even in the US I had to wait a while at a gasoline shop because the man had never seen the older $ 50 dollar note.  It was only accepted after his colleague confirmed that it was ok.

Answer (score 2):

I have Series 2006A US$100 note. When I asked at a suburban bank branch, probably on a weekend, the employee* trying to make the line move faster told me it could no longer be used. I was surprised and disappointed.

At home, I did a quick web search and found the US Treasury web pages on US$100 bills.

https://www.uscurrency.gov/denominations/100

Most importantly, ALL United States money is worth its face value. Period. The bank employee was wrong. It is never withdrawn. Any US$100 bill is worth $100. Details of how to identify a legit bill are there on the web site.

My series 2006A is from the 1996-2013 era. It has all the security feature and recognition marks. I plan to return and school them on the subject if they don't accept the bill.

https://www.uscurrency.gov/sites/default/files/downloadable-materials/files/en/100-1996-2013-features-en.pdf

1) Security thread: A thread embedded in the paper reads "USA 100", to the left of the portrait of Benjamin Franklin. Visible from both sides. Said to glow pink in UV light.

2) A water mark that echos the portrait of Franklin on the far right hand of the bill. Again, hold it up to light, its visible from either side.

3) The "100" printed in the lower right corner on the face side of the bill color shifts from green the black depending on viewing angle. Looks sparklely close-up.

4) The "100" printed on the lower left corner of the face side has "USA 100" micro-printed instead of mere hatching to make it look 'gray'.

5)"UNITED STATES OF AMERICA" are micro-printed on the edge of Franklin's lapel.

6) The printing is 3D- Treasury and Mint seals are embossed and can be recognized from the back of the bill, as are "One Hundred Dollars" and the lower "100" and "100" on the face side.

*The one who politely asks, when a line forms, "What can we do for you today?" ie, 'Can I get you out of this line somehow?', or, 'Is there any chance what you want doesn't require one of the 2 tellers on duty?'

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't really answer the question.  A forex office in the UK is not bound to accept any currency, regardless of whether it's legal tender or not.

Comment: a) Piling-on that US currency is always worth face value. 
b) Providing web address I found and used under smilar conditions